# Reader-writer problems operating systems

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

I can't understand this piece of code below because I'm not 100% understanding the concept of semaphores. Can you explain to me what is happening in this code? Specifically with the wait() and signal() functions?

Shared Data

```
semaphore mutexR , mutexW, writePending , readBlock , writeBlock;
int readCount , writeCount ;
mutexR = 1 , mutexW = 1 , writePending = 1 ,
readBlock = 1 , writeBlock = 1 ;
readCount = 0 , writeCount = 0 ;
```

• Writer Processes

```
wait (mutexW ) ;
writeCount++:
if ( writeCount == 1 ) {
wait ( readBlock ) ;
}
signal (mutexW ) ;
wait ( write Block ) ;
/∗ Do Writing /Make Reservation etc ∗/
signal ( write Block ) ;
wait (mutexW ) ;
writeCount −−;
if ( writeCount == 0 ){
signal ( readBlock ) ;
}
signal (mutexW ) ;
```

Reader Processes

```
wait ( writePending ) ;
wait ( readBlock ) ;
wait (mutexR ) ;
readCount++;
if ( readCount == 1 ){
wait ( write Block ) ;
}
signal (mutexR ) ;
signal ( readBl ock ) ;
signal ( writePending ) ;
/∗Do reading /Browse etc ∗/
wait (mutexR ) ;
readCount−−;
if ( readCount == 0 ){
signal ( write Block ) ;
}
signal (mutexR ) ;
```

Comment: I think you should edit the question and better explain what concretely you do not understand. Apparently it deals with a reader/writer critical section scheme, but you do not indicate your doubts

Comment: I did, I'm not sure what the wait() and signal() functions are doing. For e.g., does wait ( readBlock ) ; mean that there should be a block on the readers? And what does signal ( readBlock ) ; mean?

Comment: Semaphores only support two operations and have very simple semantics.  They are very well defined, and have been for decades.  Which of the (very few), concepts do you not understand?

Comment: I guess if someone could verbalize the above code, that would be helpful. I browsed the internet but because the concepts are mostly explained as definitions, I'm having trouble applying them to this specific example. What exactly is going on in the code above?

Comment: Check this link http://preshing.com/20150316/semaphores-are-surprisingly-versatile/

Comment: Thank you for the resource but I'm trying to understand what's happening in the code I provided. I have read a lot of resources but it's not helping me understand the solution above. Is it giving preference to writers?

Comment: It's your code, why don't YOU take it apart and then tell us what it does?